# join with union of multiple tables in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following data structure:

- a table `entries` with a column `entry_id`
- a table `data_int` with columns `entry_id`, `question` and `data`
- a table `data_text` with columns `entry_id`, `question` and `data`
- a table `questions` with columns `question_id`

Now I would like to make a MySQL query that does the following: for a given `entry_id` (say 222) it should select all `question_id` q from that table for which there is no row with (entry_id=222 AND question_id=q) in `data_int`, and also no such row in `data_text`. Is this possible in a single query, and if so how should I do this?

A sample data set would be

entries:

```
1
2
```

data_int:

```
1, 1, 4
1, 2, 56
1, 6, 43
1, 7, -1
```

data_text:

```
1, 3, 'hello'
1, 5, 'world'
```

questions:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Then for entry_id=1, the return value should be `4, 8, 9, 10`, since these don't appear in either data_ table for entry_id=1.

For entry_id=2, the return value should be `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` since nothing appears in any of the data_ tables.

Comment: There must be a mapping between entry_id and question_id , then only you can get as you say
 "select all question_id q from that table for which there is no row with (entry_id=222...."
So please clearly mention the table structure , or their relationship with each other

Comment: Can you please provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: I've updated the question statement. Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this.  The more efficient way with `mysql` is probably using multiple `outer join` / `null` checks.

```
select q.*
from questions q 
    left join data_int di on q.questionid = di.questionid and di.entryid = 1
    left join data_text dt on q.questionid = dt.questionid and dt.entryid = 1
where di.entryid is null and dt.entryid is null
```